# How to set input parameters for a script in Excel?

Tags: excel, office-scripts, input-parameters

I have a script that formats the data from a table to JSON. My Excel document has many sheets all with one table in each sheet. I am trying to pass in an input parameter (of type string) for the name of the sheet so that when I run the script I am able to specify the sheet that will convert the data. I currently have a default parameter "Sheet1." I don't know where I can specify the parameter when I run the script.

[Format Table Data Code Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cdj4s.png)

I know I can Just copy the script for as many sheets I have in my Excel document and hard-code it so that each script formats the data in one sheet, but for obvious reasons, I don't want to do that.

Comment: When you say "I don't know where I can specify the parameter when I run the script" do you actually mean to say "I don't know how to assign a value to the parameter"? In other words, I think you're asking how to pass arguments to an office script?

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing, there are only two ways to pass extra arguments to an office script:

1. [User Power Automate](https://make.powerautomate.com/environments/951f9b12-6ab7-e0df-b61a-d3eab17d00c7/flows/733e3887-2df4-4e90-a99a-34287e565b7b/runs/08585086810840444231783153117CU27).

> Your scripts can be written to expand the "Run script" Power Automate action to get additional input or give output.

2. [User input via a pop-up in excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/develop/user-input).

> When your script is run through the ribbon or a button, a prompt pops up that asks for input.

> **Important**: Currently, only select users in preview will be prompted to enter data for parameterized scripts in Excel on the web. Power Automate flows also support giving data to scripts through parameters.

### Use Power Automate (Option 1)

To pass an argument via Power Automate (option 1), which will be assigned to `sheetName` in your example office script, follow these steps:

1. Create a new flow in Power Automate, or edit an existing one.
2. Add a 'run script' action
3. Enter the path to your saved Excel file into the `File` field.
4. Choose the relevant script from the `Script` drop down menu.
   [image]
5. After you choose your script, new fields that correspond to the script's parameters will appear in the action menu.
   [image]
6. Enter your desired value for each field. You can type in static values, or use the features of Power Automate to supply dynamic values.